# Shared interface/data type in angular application

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `HeaderComponent` that takes an object of form `{title: string, short_desc: string}` as its input property.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: { title: string, short_desc: string };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Here is how I define data that will be passed to `HeaderComponent`:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './my-custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-custom.component.scss']
})
export class MyCustomComponent implements OnInit {
    public headerData: {title: string, short_desc: string};

    constructor() {
        this.headerData = {
            title: 'Settings Page',
            short_desc: 'Update your settings',
        }
    }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Now, I need to use `HeaderComponent` in quite a few components. So I created a file `header-data.ts` which looks like this:

```
export interface HeaderData {
    title: string;
    short_desc: string;
}
```

In order to make `HeaderComponent` work, in every component that uses it, I need to import `HeaderData` interface. This can sometimes look ugly and can break, when I decide to restructure my application.

My question is: how to use `HeaderData` interface  without need for ugly nested imports like `../../../../hero-data.ts`, or in-line object type definitions. Or maybe what I do is not the best way to go about this problem here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You apparently noticed how you usually import multiple Angular classes from @angular/... modules in a single line. That's is the Barrel feature. Please look at the [Barrel file description](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel) in the Angular docs.

While reading that text, you have to understand the difference between a JavaScript module and an Angular module. The former is a source file, the latter is a class decorated with @NgModule.

Since `interface` is not a JavaScript notion, but an abstraction in TypeScript, it is needed only in the editor and during transpilation. Module loaders don't use interface file declarations. So you can use a trick and declare it as a TypeScript definition.

Rename your file to *header-data.d.ts*, and use the word `declare` instead of `export` like the following.

```
declare interface HeaderData {
  title: string;
  short_desc: string;
}
```

So TypeScript will be able to find the `HeaderData` name at design time. This trick relies on the `"**/*.d.ts"` line in the `"include"` array in the `tsconfig.spec.json` file.

Comment: That's a nice one! However if I understand correctly, it still requires to use long relative imports (like in the example at the end of my question) in every component file.

Comment: @an0o0nym I have added an idea how to use an interface without importing it explicitly.

Comment: barrel link is broken